# What does the teacher whisper to Mr. Carroll in Smoke and Mirrors #1?

Tags: comics, smoke-and-mirrors

On page 12 of issue #1 of *Smoke and Mirrors*, the teacher whispers something to Mr Carroll to explain why the kids laughed at Ethan.

The writing is very small, and I can't make out what it says.  Zooming in just gives a larger blurry image.

I presume this is simple to read in the print edition.  What did she say?

Answer (score 1):

In the print edition this scene appears on page 8 and the teacher says

> HIS MONTHER HAS GONE TO THE OF THE MIDDLE

This is from the March 2012 First Printing. I leave the interpretation to you. Presumably some of this is lettering mistakes (yes, that's "monther", not "mother"; or maybe it's supposed to be exactly as shown and it will all become clearer as the series progresses).